# for loop in titleForRow in pickerView not working

Tags: ios, swift, for-loop, uipickerview

I was creating a clock pickerView and used the following:

```
var countSec = Array(0...10)
var countMin = Array(0...59)
var countHour = Array(0...59)

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
    if component == 0{
        for count in countSec {
            return "\(count)"
        }
    }else{
        for count in countMin{
            return "\(count)"
        }
    }
    return nil
}
```

But when I run, all the data was 0s.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use loops in `titleForRow`. Just return the appropriate value for the requested row.

```
func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
    if component == 0 {
        return "\(countSec[row])"
    } else {
        return "\(countMin[row])"
    }
}
```